# Can I use cross-signing to facilitate HPKP management?

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, pinning

HPKP in a webserver works by adding headers to replies containing hashes of various public keys, such that at least one of the hashes is *valid* = of a certificate in the certificate chain of the current server certificate, and at least one is *invalid* = not occurring in the chain and considered a backup cert.
Several strategies exist for choosing the cert to represent the valid entry:

- the root cert of your favourite CA
- the intermediate certificate of your favourite CA
- your leaf certificate

The first option is problematic as it leaves quite a large attack surface (i.e., someone might trick or coerce said CA into signing a malicious cert for your host). The second option suffers from this to a lesser extent, but more importantly the intermediate may suddenly be different when you renew, thus bricking your site (unless you used a backup CSR for the renewal). The third option is most specific, but requires you to change the HPKP header obeying very specific timing and planning ahead for a month or whatever timeout you use with the HPKP header.

I wonder if cross-signing with a personal (untrusted) CA could help, that is: Would the following scenario work out?

I obtain my cert **AAA** from the widely known and trusted CA **XXX**, who use an intermediate **YYY** to sign **AAA**. Also, I cross-sign my **AAA** cert with my obscure and totally untrustworthy and never-heard-of CA **ZZZ**. Now I configure my webserver to issue HPKP headers with **AAA,SSS,ZZZ**, where **SSS** is a safely stored backup CSR used for disaster cases.

Upon renewal, I do the same with my new cert **BBB**, i.e., I have it signed by a trusted CA (possibly by a different one, say **XX2** and intermediate **YY2**) and sign it with my own **ZZZ**; and I adjust the HPKP header to read **BBB,SSS,ZZZ**. (Actually, the HPKP header might be left at **SSS,ZZZ** from the beginning and never change)

Why do I think this should work? Let's say a visitor comes by after the switch from **AAA** to **BBB**. The TLS connection can be initiated because my server is configured to use **BBB** and the intermediate cert **YY2** as well as **ZZZ**. The client is fine with this because at least **YY2** is signed by **XX2** and that is among the client's well-known CAs. Next it checks against the HPKP header. This is either fresh and contains **BBB,ZZZ,SSS** and so is fine. Or the older version **AAA,ZZZ,SSS** is reused, which is also fine because of **ZZZ**.

**Question:** Is the method described above feasible? Will all HPKP-aware browsers work with it? Or is this even explicitly forbidden by specs?

**Additional question:** How yould I actually execute the above plan (in terms of `openssl` commands and `apache` configuration)?

Answer (score 0):

No it will not work.

The browser does not know about certificate ZZZ - unless you are intending to return it as well as the official intermediate cert XXX and/or XX2? Even if you did that the browser would completely ignore it as its untrusted and would instead build a path with the trusted root only.

HPKP adds on top of the trusted root store of browser - it doesn't replace it.

Comment: Perhaps this ignores the main idea I wanted to try: a) The browser should trust BBB because the browser can build a chain back to XX2, which is among its "hard-coded" sources of trust. b) The browser should accept BBB as valid new cert because a signer ZZZ was considered worthy by the webserver; what gets listed in HPKP cannot be directly realeted to "official trust" - after all, it works fine with fingerprints of not-even-requested-yez certificates. -- This matches your "adds on top" as BBB must be valid by to the browser's criteria (signed by XX2) and the webserver's  (signd  by ZZZ). *sigh*

Comment: Wow a 4 year follow up! The browser will use whatever trust chain it built to validate HTTPS to also test HPKP. It will not try a different chain just for HPKP. So it won’t work. Also HPKP has been removed from browsers since you originally asked this question since it was such a foot gun compared to the benefits it brought.